# VS2010RC: Can't see solutions

Tags: projects-and-solutions, visual-studio-2010

Whenever I create a new project in the Visual Studio 2010 Release Candidate, for some reason I can only see the project that I've created, and not its solution. This is a problem, as I want to add a solution to the project. Is this a bug, or have I turned off the viewing of solutions, some how?

Comment: Reported as a bug. http://bit.ly/biIY7v Microsoft says they're looking into it.

Comment: I've found a work-around. You can add a new project by going to File >> Add >> New Project. Once you do that, the solution shows up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got an answer from Microsoft. Apparently this is by design, and you can address it by checking Tools >> Options >> Projects and Solutions >> Always show solution.

Comment: Good grief! I thought I was going crazy. Thanks for this info.